# How can I get the last message from each conversation in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

**What I am looking for:**

I am looking for a SELECT query that allows me to select the last message from each conversation. A conversation is composed of all the rows that have the same users ID, for both side. *Example: 4-2 & 2-4.*

**Message Table:**

**ID**-----**Sender_ID**-----**Receiver_ID**-----**body**-----**timestamp**
1-------------------4---------------------2----------...-----------------...
2-------------------2---------------------4----------...-----------------...
3-------------------4---------------------2----------...-----------------...
4-------------------4---------------------2----------...-----------------...
5-------------------4---------------------3----------...-----------------...
6-------------------3---------------------4----------...-----------------...

**Result:**

**ID**-----**Sender_ID**-----**Receiver_ID**-----**body**-----**timestamp**
4-------------------4---------------------2----------...-----------------...
6-------------------3---------------------4----------...-----------------...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the last message from the conversation you could use a group by query to get the last ID (if it's always incrementing) or the last timestamp. User_1 will be the user with the lower id, and user_2 the user with the higher id of the conversation:

```
select
  least(sender_ID, receiver_ID) as user_1,
  greatest(sender_ID, receiver_ID) as user_2,
  max(ID) as last_id,
  max(timestamp) as last_timestamp
from
  messages
group by
  least(sender_ID, receiver_ID),
  greatest(sender_ID, receiver_ID)
```

you can then get the actual message with a query like this:

```
select m.*
from
  messages m inner join (
    select
      least(sender_ID, receiver_ID) as user_1,
      greatest(sender_ID, receiver_ID) as user_2,
      max(ID) as last_id,
      max(timestamp) as last_timestamp
    from
      messages
    group by
      least(sender_ID, receiver_ID),
      greatest(sender_ID, receiver_ID)
  ) s on least(sender_id, receiver_id)=user_1
         and greatest(sender_id, receiver_id)=user_2
         and m.id = s.last_id -- or last timestamp
```

Comment: One small question, can I use this to get the same results but choosing a ID? Let's say I want to get the last messages of user 3, there should only be 1 result, same for user 2. User 4 however should have 2 results.

Comment: yes, you could add this condition on the first or on the second query... on the first it is `... from messages where sender_id=3 or receiver_id=3 group by...` or shorter `... from messages where 3 in (sender_id, receiver_id) group by...`

Comment: Thanks again! You helped me a lot.